# Логирование сonsole.error в файл

Tags: node.js

смотря мануал наткнулся на такой код

```
console.log('normal_1');
console.error('error_1')
console.log('normal_2');
console.error('error_3')
console.log('normal_3');
console.error('error_2')

>node D:nodejs/server/server 1>ok 2>err
```

При запуске кода пишуть что console.log должен попадать в файл 1.txt а сonsole.error в файл 2.txt но ничего не происходит и при запуске команды все зависает

Comment: А эта странная буква D что означает? `D:nodejs`

Comment: запускаю сценарий с диска D

Comment: Там никаких слешей не надо типа `D:\nodejs\...` ?